# OOP assign socket script to multiple object

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, oop

I'm not so common with OOP, and I would to transfer data with a socket from a c++ file to a c#. In c# i have one script which receive all the data and assign parts of them respectively to obj 1 and obj 2(see image below). However I don't know which of the configuration below matches with the reality. 
When I assign this script to both objects, can it be that one of the objects get all the data the other one none of them? Or both object receive all the data?

[image: option1 both object receive all the data]

[image: option2 the data flows randomly to one of the script and data get lost]

Comment: I'm not sure that sideways photos of a sketch add more value to your question than a simple description of what you want!

Comment: More importantly, you've shown us no code whatsoever. Diagnosing and assisting with code problems is quite hard when you haven't shared your code.